# Predict(), NewData with two column and differing rows

Tags: r, multiple-columns, prediction, glm, poisson

I am trying to make the prediction of three variables (`retweets`,`media`,`content`) in my dataset (`df_22`) to choose between Poisson, Negative binomial and Zero-inflated Poisson. One of the three variables is the response variable (`retweets`) and the other two the predictive variables (`media`,`content`).

I realize the generalized linear models and without problem.

**Zero-inflated Poisson data**

```
 library("pscl")
 summary( m0 <- zeroinfl(retweets ~ media + content, data=df_22,dist="poisson") )
```

**Poisson**

```
summary( m1 <- glm(formula=retweets ~ media + content, data=df_22, family="poisson"(link=log)))
```

**Negative binomial**

```
library (MASS) 
summary( m2 <- glm.nb(retweets ~ media + content, data=df_22) )
```

However, when I create the new database to make the prediction. I check it levels.

```
> levels(df_22$media)
[1] "other" "pic"   "pw"    "text"  "web"

> levels(df_22$content)
[1] "cultura"     "employ"      "environment" "other"       "security"    "sport"       "transport"
```

I have a problem. And it is that the rows of both columns is different.

```
newmedia = c("other","pic","pw","text", "web")
newcontent = c("cultura","employ","environment","other","security","sport","transport")

nd = data.frame(media = newmedia, content = newcontent)
```

> Error in data.frame(media = newmedia, content = newcontent) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 7

**What should I do to solve these problems?**

I want to solve this problem in order to be able to make these predictions so that I can choose which of the three models is better for my data.

```
p0 <- cbind(nd, Count = predict(m0, newdata = nd, type = "count"), Zero = predict(m0, newdata = nd, type = "zero"))

p1 <- cbind(nd, Mean = predict(m1, newdata = nd, type="response"), SE = predict(m1, newdata = nd, type="response", se.fit=T)$se.fit)

p2 <- cbind(nd, Mean = predict(m2, newdata = nd, type="response"), SE = predict(m2, newdata = nd, type="response", se.fit=T)$se.fit)
```

Comment: how should your data.frame `nd` look?
you could try `nd<-expand.grid(newmedia,newcontent)
names(nd)<-c("media","content")` if you want all combinations

Answer (score 0):

In the `code` below a sample `data` set is created and it computes the `p0`, `p1`, `p2`. The `nb dataframe` was created differently as a `test dataframe`.

**Import libraries**

```
library(pscl)
library (MASS)
```

**Create sample data set**

```
media <- c("other", "pic",   "pw",    "text",  "web")
content <- c("cultura", "employ", "environment", "other", "security", "sport", "transport")

set.seed(1)
retweets <- floor(abs(1e4*rnorm(1000)))
temp_index <- which(retweets %in% sample(retweets, 20)) # sample indexes
retweets[temp_index] <- 0 # set some retweets to zero to run zeroinfl()
df <- data.frame(retweets)
df$media <- sample(media, 1000, replace = TRUE)
df$content <- sample(content, 1000, replace = TRUE)
head(df)

unique(df$media)
unique(df$content)
```

**Create a test data set**

Note: Here, test data set is drawn from the training data for illustration purpose only. Ideally, it should be a new set of data.

```
nd = df[sample(nrow(df), 300), ] # ideally this should not be from the train data, this is just for an example code
nd_X <- test[,c('media', 'content')]
nd_Y <- test[,c('retweets')]
```

**Fit models: `zeroinf(dist='poisson')`, `glm(family='poisson')`, `glm.nb()`**

```
# Poisson
summary( m0 <- zeroinfl(retweets ~ media + content, data=df, dist="poisson") )

# Binomial
summary( m1 <- glm(formula=retweets ~ media + content, data=df, family="poisson"(link=log)))

# glm()
#summary( m2 <- glm.nb(retweets ~ media + content, data=df) )  # gives error in summary due to zeros
summary( m2 <- glm.nb(retweets ~ media + content, data=df[df$retweets!=0,]) ) # no error without zeros
```

**`Predict` using `test data` set**

```
p0 <- cbind(nd, Count = predict(m0, newdata = nd_X, type = "count"), Zero = predict(m0, newdata = nd, type = "zero"))
p1 <- cbind(nd, Mean = predict(m1, newdata = nd_X, type="response"), SE = predict(m1, newdata = nd, type="response", se.fit=T)$se.fit)
p2 <- cbind(nd, Mean = predict(m2, newdata = nd_X, type="response"), SE = predict(m2, newdata = nd, type="response", se.fit=T)$se.fit)
```

Output:

[image]